# How to use uber api for price estimate in php

Tags: php, api, uber-api

I am using uber api in my project for the first time. I want to get a price estimate through the uber api. I am getting this result:

> {"message":"No authentication provided.","code":"unauthorized"}

My source code is this:

```
$token = "acess token"; 


 $header=array(  
     "Authorization: Token $token",
     "Content-Type: application/json",
     "Accept-Language: en_US"

 // CALCULATE FAIR

 $url  =  "https://api.uber.com/v1.2/estimates/price?start_latitude=37.7752315&start_longitude=-122.418075&end_latitude=37.7752415&end_longitude=-122.518075"; 


 $curl=curl_init();
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH,$header); 
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$token:");
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   
 $output1 = curl_exec($curl);

  echo "<pre>";
 print_r($output1);
```

Comment: have a look at this github projects for uber PHP API https://github.com/stevenmaguire/uber-php and https://github.com/f3ath/simpleuber

Comment: yeah...i tried this...but no benefit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your code, please use below code.. it is working

`curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH,$header);` should be replaced with `curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);`

**Please note: never ever put your Authentication tokens like this on a public website, it can be misused, please re-generate a new token and delete the old one.**

```
<?php

$token = "your_auth_token";


$header = array(
    "Authorization: Token $token",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Accept-Language: en_US");

// CALCULATE FAIR

$url = "https://api.uber.com/v1.2/estimates/price?start_latitude=37.7752315&start_longitude=-122.418075&end_latitude=37.7752415&end_longitude=-122.518075";


$curl    = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $token);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$output1 = curl_exec($curl);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($output1);
```